# Is Fermat's Last theorem equivalent to $1 + 1 = 2$?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I got into a debate with someone concerning whether FLT is equivalent to $1 + 1 =2$. He said common sense tells us it isn't equivalent.  However, I disagreed.  Since both are provable statements, they are equivalent.  Which one of us is correct?

Comment: Any two *true* statements are indeed logically equivalent

Comment: Equivalent means different things in different contexts.  They are not equivalent expressions.  They are not of equivalent difficulty.  They are equivalent in terms of whether they are true or not.  It is a common mistake in language to assume that there is only 1 kind of equivalence, one that you and your friend seem to have made.

Comment: When you explained why you held this position, this did not settle the debate with your friend? I am asking you this because one can foresee you will receive answers essentially repeating what you already know about logical equivalence... so what is the point of the question?

Comment: Do you take some Platonistic approach to mathematics, where somethings are just true and others are just false? What about unprovable things, are they true or false? What does "equivalent" even mean for you?

Comment: If equivalent means "lead to roughly the same pattern of neuronal firing in a mathematically fluent English-speaking listener," then no, they're not that.

Answer (score 3):

In a realm of discourse (say, "ordinary mathematics", or ZFC) where both are provably true, or provably false, or each is provably true or false assuming that the other is true or false, they're equivalent.  Tacitly assuming that we're *in* such a realm (since FLT has now been proven), you're correct.  They're not *semantically* equivalent statements, though (i.e., they don't *mean* the same thing): you can imagine axiom schemas under which neither is provable, even assuming the other; and in such a universe, they are inequivalent.  If your friend's "common sense" includes this metamathematical wrinkle, then he is correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic tells us that 
$$
P \longleftrightarrow Q
$$
is true as long $P=Q=True$ or $P=Q=False$. So yes they are !